# How to check if a dialog is open in PowerPoint?

Tags: c#, office-interop

I have an application written in C# using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint`. This application opens a PowerPoint presentation file to the user. The user interacts with the file. After applying some modifications, the user submits the file through the application submit button.

The Problem:
When user modifies the content of the presentation, for example changes font color of the text to red, by using a dialog and keeps the dialog open without clicking on "Apply" or "OK" button and thereby submits the file by clicking on application submit button, those dialog done changes aren't reflected in the submitted file and hence such changes can't be tracked of.

I somehow want to alert a user to close any open dialog before clicking on submit button.

I do this easily on Word and excel files by checking Exception on saving such files because Word and Excel throws exception on using save method if there is any dialog open, like the Following:

```
try{
    document.Save();
}
catch (Exception e){
//Alert user here here
}
```

but this doesn't work for PowerPoint files. I tried the following:

```
PowerPointApplication application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentations presentations = application.Presentations;

Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation presentation =
                    presentations
                    .Open(file, WithWindow: Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue,ReadOnly:Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,Untitled:Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse);
```

The following is triggered on Submit button click event:

```
try
            {              
                    presentation.Save();
                
            }            
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //alert user here
            }
```

Is there a way to track if there are any open dialog boxes?

Answer (score 0):

Typically if any dialog window is displayed to a user the code is blocked because the dialog window uses the main thread for running. Do you use multiple threads in the code?

Anyway, you can use Windows API functions for detecting the active window, see [GetActiveWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getactivewindow) which retrieves the window handle to the active window attached to the calling thread's message queue. To get the handle to the foreground window, you can use [GetForegroundWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getforegroundwindow). To get the window handle to the active window in the message queue for another thread, use [GetGUIThreadInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getguithreadinfo).

After retrieving the window handle you can use the [GetWindowText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtexta?redirectedfrom=MSDN) function which copies the text of the specified window's title bar (if it has one) into a buffer. If the specified window is a control, the text of the control is copied.

Comment: Thank you for taking time. Do you use multiple threads in the code? Yes.

Comment: That is not really a good idea. Most Office applications uses the single-threaded apartment model, moreover you should deal with UI on the main thread only. So, I'd suggest moving your code to the main thread.